# Angular Component On destroy need to check if Data is saved or not and get Confirmation?

Tags: angular

Before Angular component is getting destroyed I need to get a confirmation from the user to save the changes or Destroy the component.

Things which I tried:

1. tried to use CanDeactivate guard, but in my case the component is not loading from the routing it is loaded as sub component, so that I cannot add canDeactivate Guard to that component.
2. I tried to figure out using onDestroy of the component, but I cannot destroy the component conditionally as it is of type Void, so I cannot get confirmation from the user before destroying the component.

Is there any other way that I can get confirmation from user before destroying the component?

Comment: The only way is to use can deactivate. Can't you route your component ?

Comment: You should handle this at the action that triggers the destruction. Whether it's a click or a page nagivation.

Comment: @Maryannah I cannot route my component as is deeply nested and also have to handle many inputs and outputs in this component... Thanks..)

Comment: @AvinKavish, I can do that, but there are many events and also page navigation which can trigger the destruction. Listening to all these events and navigation's would be complex and not that performance friendly , so thought to fix this from Angular's component perspective, .....Thanks....:)

Comment: Can't you apply CanDeactivate to whatever parent component that is routed? IIRC, child components don't get destroyed if the parent cannot deactivate.

Comment: @AvinKavish, My parent component has 3-4 sub components, where even if one of sub components gets destroyed parent still stays there, which means that the CanDeactivate of parent will not be called unless parent gets destroyed , if I am not wrong ........:)

Comment: aahh.... so you are switching components manually as well as routing..... I don't think a lifecycle hook can stop this, they are hooks. not interrupts. And if a component does not disappear based on the binding there will be a disparity between state and the view. The best suggestion I can give is `CanDeactivate` to prevent a route change from destroying the parent component and the same logic in whatever local events that could destroy the component. My understanding is that your logic is causing this, so only your logic can prevent it.

Comment: Try listening to state in ngOnChanges and cancelling the state change that causes the component to be destroyed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195046/discussion-between-shiva-nayak-dharavath-and-avin-kavish).

Answer (score 0):

> CanDeactivate Guard will solve this problem

```
    @Injectable()
    export class CanDeactivateGuard implements 
              CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean {

    if(!component.canDeactivate()){
        if (confirm("You have unsaved changes! If you leave, your changes will 
             be lost.")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

[Please follow this blog](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d)

> The other way

```
    import { NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';

  private routeSub:any;  // subscription to route observer

  public ngOnInit() {
    /* 
       Register to Angular navigation events to detect navigating away (so we can save changed settings for example)
    */
    this.routeSub = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // save your data
      }
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @RajuPedda, as I already mentioned in my question, my scenario is my component is not loading via routing, so either of your solutions will not work for me, anyway thanks....:)